# The remote server returned an error: "(405) Method Not Allowed"

Tags: c#

After reading different answers against the same thread i tried almost all the options mentioned in their discussions however i am still getting error:

**Error No1**: *`The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`* OR

**Error No2**:*`The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed`.*

Below is my code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL?Paramter1=pc&user=u1&password=p1");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I receive error on the last line i.e.

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

If i use `httpWebRequest.Method="GET"` i receive the error number 1 as mentioned above and if i use `httpWebRequest.Method="Post"` i receive the error number 2.

Comment: Where are you returning the json from?

Comment: Can you be more specific ... ??? i am returning it from server (ofcourse)

Comment: I suppose that you do not know the calling method if is post or get? EDIT: Do you know what are the parameters of the web call?

Comment: Yes, but how does the returning method look? Not really sure what you mean, but when I return json from my controllers, I need to add a `JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet` as part of my returned result.

Comment: @kostasch. infact i do know its post.. but alot of other threads where saying we should change it here and there to see if it works..thats why i already mentioned it in my question, otherwise its "post" which you can in my code.

Comment: Ok, if is post stay Post, but do you know it's pattern? I mean the name of parameters and IF you have to give more parameters as object? I mean except from 3 params you set in url are you sure that method do not expect and an object , a class for example ?

Comment: Are you doing cross domain?

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE Yes I am using c# but probably person who wrote server side code dont have any idea about c#

Comment: @kostasch. It accepts only 3 paramters..this is what i have been told

Comment: @NicklasWinger Not sure Nicklas

Comment: The server must to accept cross domain requests. Without this, you can't make cross domain requests.

Comment: And i suppose they gave you a working example of the call. Have you have any proxy on your pc?

Comment: @kostasch. no proxy..

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE seems reasonable...let me check with other group..

Comment: Well finally i got it.. there wasnt any issue with the code.. the user which they gave me to check the functionality wasnt not a valid user.. So system was returning exception of invalid user.. However i have another question though... why system didnt raise exception.. why it was giving error 404? I had checked with other group they were raising the execption properly... is there something wrong with my code then? although I wrote my code in try catch block...

Answer (score 1):

I too face this issue. Root cause of this error is may be mistook endpoint address in web config file..

This is my mistaken web config

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="sample.sample">
    <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:9335" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="sample.Isamplebase" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:9335" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

It should be like this

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="sample.sample">
    <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:9335/sample.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="sample.Isamplebase" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:9335" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Now its working fine... Best is yours.. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "abcxx")]
```

At your service page where you declare your method, type `POST` in upper case. I think you are typing in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that either Paramter1 or username or password are incorrect - in other words the user you were trying to use doid not exist.

The server returns *404 Not Found*, not because you didn't hit the right API method, but because the object you are asking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you create your URL and pass data as url form encoded, but then you set the content type as `application/json`. I'd think you either:

1. Meant to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type

or

2. Meant to not send the data in the URL, and instead need to set a JSON body for your POST

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. In my case the reason was in incorrect (incomplete) URL.

I called

60033/COMPANY_NAME/api/Company/MOM/v1.0/companies(5a56e3ea-cd63-ec11-b6ea-6045bd874170)/

But you can’t do a POST on the general companies-URL.

I should use URL different headers, depends on my purpose

60033/COMPANY_NAME/api/Company/MOM/v1.0/companies(5a56e3ea-cd63-ec11-b6ea-6045bd874170)/receiptHeaders

When I fixed URL errors are gone